# How to make a django model singleton

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have django model which stores file and uploded peron but i need my django model to be a singleton how can i acheive this?

**models.py**

```
class Mymodel(BaseModel):
     title = models.FileField(
        upload_to='',
        validators=[],
    )
     person_uploaded = models.Foreignkey()
```

Comment: To make it a singleton you would use a `OneToOne` field, not a `ForeignKey` but your model doesn't make sense anyway. Which model is the foreign key for?

Comment: @Selcuk the data for accounts lies in other model hence foreignkey

Comment: Which other model? You are not passing a model name to your `ForeignKey` constructor (you also have a typo in the class name).

Answer (score 0):

for the OP, please follow some tutorial about model relationships on official site just like the comments suggested.

---

for visitors who searched the title and tried to implement a table of constants.

I thought about this through architecture initially, and played around. then django taught me a tough lesson, **you better not mess model structure, do with what you normally use, otherwise something may go wrong**, so I ended up implementing this:

```py
import math
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Constants(models.Model):
    pi = models.FloatField(default=math.pi)
    e = models.FloatField(default=math.e)

    @staticmethod
    def setup():
        try:
            Constants.objects.get(pk=1)
        except Constants.DoesNotExist:
            instance = Constants()
            instance.save()

    @staticmethod
    def instance():
        return Constants.objects.get(pk=1)
    
    # only create 1 and save 1 allowed, other abort
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:
            try:
                Constants.objects.get(pk=1)
            except Constants.DoesNotExist:
                # create 1
                super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # save 1
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

which only allow `pk=1` exist, and always use that instance, you can update it, and remember to run `setup` to initialise first instance and `default` values after deploy to server. this saves performance, and will causing any bug.